# Update RAID 10 NAS storage

Tags: raid, storage, network-attached-storage, update, raid10

I've got a NAS with 4x500GB HDD in RAID 10. I want to change the actual HDDs to others of 1TB capacity, but I want (if possible) to preserve the data without having to copy it outside the NAS. The NAS I'm using is a Synology DS411.

Right now this should be the layout:

```
HDD#1(500GB) = A1
HDD#2(500GB) = A1
HDD#3(500GB) = A2
HDD#4(500GB) = A2
```

The idea is changing *HDD#2* and *HDD#4* for the new 1TB HDDs so *HDD#1* and *HDD#3* copy the data to the new HDDs, then swap *HDD#1* and *HDD#3* with the other 1TB HDD when the RAID is rebuilded. Is this possible or should I backup all the data to an external source and then rebuild the RAID from scratch with the new HDDs?

Comment: What NAS storage do you use? Some storage don't support hot increasing of logical unit where located you partition.

Comment: I'm using a Synology DS411.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should backup anyway. Point. No backup means the data is useless to you - congratulation. Things ALWAYS can go bad.

Second, i would just go disc by disc. Take out, rebuild until finished, one disc after the next.

Comment: Took around 1 hour per disk to rebuild the RAID, but Synology NAS went without problems with the upgrade.